# How to filter data with lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have code as follows:

```
data = [
  {id: "15130", state: "INITIAL"},
  {id: "15129", state: "LOCKED"},
  {id: "10314", state: "APPROVED"},
  {id: "51", state: "APPROVED"},
  {id: "10313", state: "APPROVED_LOCKED"},
  {id: "10315", state: "APPROVED_LOCKED"}
]

filters = [{id: "2", name: "LOCKED", count: 2}]

let result = []

_.forEach(data, (ca) => {  
  if (filters.length > 0) {
    if (!_.some(filters, (item) => item.name === ca.state.includes('LOCKED') ? "LOCKED" : ca.state))
      return;
  }
  result.push(ca);
});

console.log(result)
```

I want to get all records from data where state includes `"LOCKED"`. Thus result should be:

```
result = [
  {id: "15129", state: "LOCKED"},
  {id: "10313", state: "APPROVED_LOCKED"},
  {id: "10315", state: "APPROVED_LOCKED"}
]
```

But I get all records in result.

[Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/k4x3socb/2/)

Any idea what I do wrong?

Comment: does `count` have a meaning here?

Comment: @NinaScholz No. Its only `name` what matters.

Answer (score 2):

No need for Lodash, you can use Vanilla JavaScript's [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), followed by [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) which checks if the string value in `state` contains the string 'LOCKED'.

```js
const data = [
  {id: "15130", state: "INITIAL"},
  {id: "15129", state: "LOCKED"},
  {id: "10314", state: "APPROVED"},
  {id: "51", state: "APPROVED"},
  {id: "10313", state: "APPROVED_LOCKED"},
  {id: "10315", state: "APPROVED_LOCKED"}
]

const res = data.filter(obj => obj['state'].includes('LOCKED'));

console.log(res);
```

However, do take note that Array.includes() is not as [widely supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: I can also have `filters = [{id: "2", name: "LOCKED", count: 2}, {id: "1", name: "APPROVED", count: 2}]`

Comment: @Boky I see! Basically, filter the records whereby state can include 'LOCKED' or 'APPROVED'?

Comment: APPROVED is always APPROVED, but with LOCKED I can have LOCKED_APPROVED, LOCKED_INITIAL and LOCKED. Thus for APPROVED I do not need includes, it can be `===` but for LOCKED I need includes.

Comment: I think it would be cleaner to have a list of exact matches you want to exclude, rather than do a partial match on the state. Imagine in the future a state shows up that's "UNLOCKED", at which point it partially matches "LOCKED" and it gets filtered out. EDIT: just to clarify - this was aimed at OP. This solution only follows OP's request.

Comment: In that case, it follows a similar logic - iterate through the list of filters, and conditionally handle it based on the state?

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the array by checking each `name` of the filters array.

```js
var data = [{ id: "15130", state: "INITIAL" }, { id: "15129", state: "LOCKED" }, { id: "10314", state: "APPROVED" }, { id: "51", state: "APPROVED" }, { id: "10313", state: "APPROVED_LOCKED" }, { id: "10315", state: "APPROVED_LOCKED" }],
    filters = [{ id: "2", name: "LOCKED", count: 2 }, { id: "1", name: "APPROVED", count: 2 }],
    result = data.filter(({ state }) => filters.some(({ name }) => state.includes(name)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const allowedStatus = ["APPROVED_LOCKED", "LOCKED" ];

data.filter(filter => allowedStatus.includes(filter.state));
```

You can have an array with allowd status and filter the data with that. Try above code.

Answer (score 0):

**How to do it with `lodash`:**

Since you do not need to modify the original array, you may use [_.filter](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#filter) . The required arguments are the input array and the predicate which will be used to filter the provided array.

```js
    const data = [
      {id: "15130", state: "INITIAL"},
      {id: "15129", state: "LOCKED"},
      {id: "10314", state: "APPROVED"},
      {id: "51", state: "APPROVED"},
      {id: "10313", state: "APPROVED_LOCKED"},
      {id: "10315", state: "APPROVED_LOCKED"}
    ]

    const result = _.filter(data, (elem => {return elem.state.includes("LOCKED")}));

    console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

In case you want to modify the original array, `_.remove` is an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pure JS:

```js
 

const data = [
  {id: "15130", state: "INITIAL"},
  {id: "15129", state: "LOCKED"},
  {id: "10314", state: "APPROVED"},
  {id: "51", state: "APPROVED"},
  {id: "10313", state: "APPROVED_LOCKED"},
  {id: "10315", state: "APPROVED_LOCKED"}
];

const res = data.filter(({ state }) => state.includes("LOCKED"));

console.log(res);
```

```css
 

.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```